# Iterate through each dataframe header and update int month to str month if and only if the header string has '20' in it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A few Django formatting issues which require df header changes.

Test data:

```
Test_Data = [
                ('Year_Month', ['Done_RFQ','Not_Done_RFQ','Total_RFQ']),
                ('2018_11', [10, 20, 30]),
                ('2019_06',[10,20,30]),
                ('2019_12', [40, 50, 60]),
             ]

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Test_Data))
print(df)

     Year_Month  2018_11  2019_06  2019_12
0      Done_RFQ       10       10       40
1  Not_Done_RFQ       20       20       50
2     Total_RFQ       30       30       60
```

Desired output:

```
     Year_Month  2018_Nov  2019_Jun  2019_Dec
0      Done_RFQ        10        10        40
1  Not_Done_RFQ        20        20        50
2     Total_RFQ        30        30        60
```

My attempt:

```
df_names = df.columns
for df_name in df_names:
    if df_name[:1] == '20':
        df.df_name = str(pd.to_datetime(df_name, format='%Y_%m').dt.strftime('%Y_%b'))
```

Error: `AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'dt'`

I was hoping the date object could be used for the formatting. Any sgguestions on how to genearalise this for any string in the headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
s=pd.Series(df.columns)
s2=pd.to_datetime(s,format='%Y_%m',errors ='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y_%b')
df.columns=s2.mask(s2=='NaT').fillna(s)
df
Out[368]: 
   2018_Nov  2019_Jun  2019_Dec    Year_Month
0        10        10        40      Done_RFQ
1        20        20        50  Not_Done_RFQ
2        30        30        60     Total_RFQ
```

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the .dt since  .strftime is a method for Timestamp:

```
df.df_name = str(pd.to_datetime(df_name, format='%Y_%m').strftime('%Y_%b'))
```

Comment: Hi @Andy Hayden, the df.df_name assignment appears not to be updating the column headers. Still seeing 2018_11 etc